# jQuery/JavaScript toggle button to add Inline styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to create a toggle button to add inline styles?

For example in this simple structure i want to make a toggle button to show or hide the div 
I do not want to add a class name or using only ***.show()*** and ***.hide()*** in jQuery

I need it to be Inline style for example If i toggle the button i want it to add this style

```
style="display:block color:red;"
```

and if you toggle again

```
style="display:none"
```

```html
<button>toggle</button>

<div>blah bla blah</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check toggle style with `.css("display")` .Then set attribute as you wanted to do

```
$("button").click(function(){
        if($("div").css("display") == "none") {
             $("div").css({"display":"block","color":"red"});
        }
        else{
            $('div').css("display","none");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thats what i was looking for Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 3):

try below code...

```
<button id="button">toggle</button>

<div id="div">blah bla blah</div>
```

JavaScript code...

```
var button=document.getElementById("button");
var div=document.getElementById("div");
div.style.display="block";

button.onclick=function (){
    if(div.style.display=="block"){
        div.style.display="none";
    }
    else{
        div.style.display="block";
    }
}
```

live [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/rwzx25ax/)

Happy coding... :)

Comment: It works fine, but i have used the jQuery one. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use custom classes and `toggleClass()`

```
.costomclass {
  display:block color:red;
}
.normalClass {
  display:none
}

<div class="normalClass">blah bla blah</div>

$(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    $('.normalClass').toggleClass('costomclass');
  });

});
```

Comment: Sorry, as i have mentioned i want it to be inline styles, but thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

simplified toggle version

```
div.style.display=div.style.display==='none'?'block':'none';
```

snippet

```js
var button=document.getElementById("button");
var div=document.getElementById("div"); 
  button.onclick=function (){
div.style.display=div.style.display==='none'?'block':'none';<-----single line

}
```

```html
<button id="button">toggle</button>
<div id="div">blah bla blah</div>
```